# Form Validation with Array and User Input

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, validation, while-loop

I have set up a user input box to enter a number (1 through 3) to show that many FAQS on my site. I also would like to use a form validation to inform the user that they have left the input box empty. The array prints just fine with the user input, but the form validation does not throw an alert when the input box is left empty.

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="block3"><br/><br/>
        <a name="FAQs"><img id="img2" src="pic2.JPG" alt="Computer" />
        <h2>FAQs</h2></a>
            <p id="p01">
            Enter a number (up to 3):
            <input type="text" id="FAQS_list" placeholder="Enter Number Here" />, and
            <button value="Click" onclick="listFAQS()" onSubmit="return validateForm()">Click</button> to see that many Frequently Asked Questions.<br/><br/><br/></p>
        <p id="FAQS"></p>
        <script src="expExternal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and here is the Javascript

```
     function listFAQS() {var arrayFAQ = ["FAQ1", "FAQ2", "FAQ3"];

var n = document.getElementById('FAQS_list').value;
var x = 0;
  var text = "";
  while (x < n) {
text += arrayFAQ[x] + "<br>";
x++;}
document.getElementById('FAQS').innerHTML = text;
}
// Form Validation
function validateForm() {
var y = document.getElementById("FAQS_list").value;
if (y == "") {
    alert("Please enter a number.");
    return false;
}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to control size of your arrayFAQ before or in while loop statment, otherwise your list contain additional n-3 number of **undefined**.

```
   while ( n <= arrayFAQ.length && x < n ) {
         text += arrayFAQ[x] + "<br>";
         x++;
    }
```

If you want add new elements to the array arrayFAQ and display them all,
add one if block after

```
var n = document.getElementById('FAQS_list').value;
```

like this

```
if (isNaN(n)) {
    arrayFAQ.push(n);
    n = arrayFAQ.length;
}
```

Comment: Seams that you changed your question. 
Just add as first line of the function listFAQS() 

if(!validateForm()) return;

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to use the form tag and onsubmit event handler.
2. Modify the type of the button to `submit`.
   Please see the code below for reference:

```js
function listFAQS() {
  var arrayFAQ = ["FAQ1", "FAQ2", "FAQ3"];

  var n = document.getElementById('FAQS_list').value;
  var x = 0;
  var text = "";
  while (x < n) {
    text += arrayFAQ[x] + "<br>";
    x++;
  }
  document.getElementById('FAQS').innerHTML = text;

}
// Form Validation
function validateForm() {
  var y = document.getElementById("FAQS_list").value;
  if (y == "") {
    alert("Please enter a number.");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="return validateForm()" action="/" method="post">
  <a name="FAQs">
    <img id="img2" src="pic2.JPG" alt="Computer" />
    <h2>FAQs</h2>
  </a>
  <p id="p01">
    Enter a number (up to 3):
    <input type="text" id="FAQS_list" placeholder="Enter Number Here" />, and
    <button type="submit" value="Click" onclick="listFAQS()">Click</button> to see that many Frequently Asked Questions.<br /><br /><br />
  </p>
  <p id="FAQS"></p>
</form>
```